# using do until_loop how its possible to search and get values within a certain range

Tags: excel, vba

i create a macro using DO UNTIL ... LOOP to get me the last 8 values from a sheet, now I need basically the same formula but with two values as range

I'm sure its possible the how is my problem
thanks

```
Cells(Application.Rows.Count, col_oleo).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 0).Select
oleo8 = ActiveCell.Value
oleo_hora8 = Cells(Application.Rows.Count, col_oleo).End(xlUp).Offset(0, col_oleo_hora).Value

Do Until oleo7 <> ""
Selection.Offset(-1, 0).Select
oleo7 = Selection.Value
oleo_hora7 = Selection.Offset(0, col_oleo_hora).Value
Loop

Do Until oleo6 <> ""
Selection.Offset(-1, 0).Select
oleo6 = Selection.Value
oleo_hora6 = Selection.Offset(0, col_oleo_hora).Value
Loop
```

something like this but instead <> "" it should be <30 and >25

```
Do Until oleo7 <30 and >25
Selection.Offset(-1, 0).Select
oleo7 = Selection.Value
oleo_hora7 = Selection.Offset(0, col_oleo_hora).Value
Loop

Do Until oleo6 <30 and >25
Selection.Offset(-1, 0).Select
oleo6 = Selection.Value
oleo_hora6 = Selection.Offset(0, col_oleo_hora).Value
loop
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to include the variable in every comparison in the Statement.

```
Do Until oleo7 < 30 And oleo7 > 25
    Selection.Offset(-1, 0).Select
    oleo7 = Selection.Value
    oleo_hora7 = Selection.Offset(0, col_oleo_hora).Value
Loop

Do Until oleo6 < 30 And oleo6 > 25
    Selection.Offset(-1, 0).Select
    oleo6 = Selection.Value
    oleo_hora6 = Selection.Offset(0, col_oleo_hora).Value
loop
```